# What should be the permissions on /var/tmp/mysite if my PHP script writes there?

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, apache2

I (PHP newbie) am setting up a legacy PHP website on my Linux/Apache server.

When I test the site in my browser I get this error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/tmp/jinfo/Circuit/best_cities.csv):
failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/jinfo/includes/jinfo.inc.php on line 89 
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpMLE9Ox' to
'/var/tmp/jinfo/Circuit/best_cities.csv' in
/var/www/jinfo/includes/jinfo.inc.php on line 89
```

Looks like a file system permissions problem. The script uses `/var/tmp/jinfo` and its subfolders to store files. The permissions on that directory are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Aug  7 15:32 jinfo
```

Since Apache is running as user www-data, the error message is expected. But what should the permissions be? I am sure there are lots of ways to make the error message go away by loosening permissions, but I want to follow the best practice. Should I change the owner (chown) to www-data, or chmod the permissions?

Note: I need the changes to propagate to subdirectories too.

Comment: What's the user/group for the file `/tmp/phpMLE9Ox`?

Comment: Not sure, since those files seem to get deleted so quickly I can't even see their permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your permissions before changing the group will be effective. As mentioned in Explosion Pill's answer, you should change the group to be `www-data` for Apache. You can do this recursively on your `/var/www` directory:

```
chown -R owner:www-data /var/www
```

where `owner` is the user that currently owns the files.

Here you can see the read/write/execute permissions on the file for the owner, group, and others respectively:

> drwxr-xr-x

Ignore the `d`, the other letters mean:

- owner - read write execute
- group - read ------ execute
- others - read ------ execute

This site gives you the meaning of the `chmod` numbers:

http://www.goldenplanet.com/support/kb/articles/changing-of-file-rights-chmod-on-the-webserver.html

```
0: No rights 
1: Execute
2: Write
3: Write/Execute
4: Read
5: Read/Execute
6: Read/Write
7: Read/Write/Execute
```

You can do `chmod 775` *on the directory that is giving the permission error* which will give the owner of the file and the group full permissions, while only giving "others," read and execute access.

Comment: `chmod g+w` would be preferred

Comment: I clarified that part, also @RexE make sure that you add your user to the `www-data` group if you're not already in it, otherwise you might be forced to edit files as root.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to chgroup on that folder to the www-data group and add group-write permissions (or create a new group with www-data in it, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

I think the better option would be to either chown or chgroup then chmod in order to provide the permission to the user/group to write to the file.

```
chgrp -R www-data /var/tmp/jinfo

        OR
```

chown -R root:www-data /var/tmp/jinfo

Both of them would produce the same output.Then change the permission, by giving permission to the group to write-access the folder.

```
chmod 775 or chmod 665 or chmod g+w /var/tm/jinfo -R
```

to give write access to the group.